# Does Ext.override() create a new function if it doesn't exist already?

Tags: javascript, extjs, overriding

Just wondering if Ext.override() add a new function to the class on which I am calling it if the function does not exist already (in the class)?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.override` focused on the specified target with the given values.

1. If the target is a class declared , the override method of that class is called.
2. If the target is a function, it is assumed to be a constructor and the contents of overrides are applied to its prototype using `EXT.apply`.
3. **If the target is none of these, the overrides are applied to the target using** [Ext.apply](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/Ext.html#method-apply)

Answer (score 1):

**Ext.override()** will add your new functions to class even if they are new. It only calls **Ext.apply()** to yours class prototype inside. You can check this in **ext-all-debug-w-comments.js** file related to yours ExtJS version which is non-minified and contains docs/comments.